# How do I make visual studio abort and print stack trace on exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I hit an exception in visual studio I want the process to die and to see a stack trace. Instead, I get dialogs that slow me down and now immediately visible stack trace. If I have exception assistant enabled I get the exception assistant window on exceptions. If I disable it, I still get a dialog that asks me if I want to break or continue. This is seriously slowly down my workflow.

The desired workflow is to press `f5`, see stacktrace in output without clicking or pressing any buttons, edit code, repeat. So my problem is twofold: the mandatory dialogs are slowing me down and the stacktrace is not obviously visible.

EDIT: The problem is VS, not the fact that the code has exceptions in it...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could add logging to the application and not break on exceptions when debugging.  Then exceptions would simply be written to the log.  In your exception handlers you can terminate the application.

Comment: Changes to the application are not an acceptable workaround for a workflow problem like this.

Comment: Are you asking about executing(debugging) in VS?  Or are you asking about for a compiled and deployed executable that was *made* by VS?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Executing in VS.

Comment: I am curious why people are voting to close this as too broad. I am asking about removing a very specific dialog box when debugging code in VS. Let me know what else I should add if you are confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can't get what you want with the stock visual studio. However using their [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx), specifically the [exception handling portion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb146610.aspx), I am fairly confident that what you want is achievable, you will just need to write a extension to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try writing an extension to handle this.

Comment: @Skyler The DTE event [`DebuggerEventsClass.OnExceptionNotHandled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debuggereventsclass.onexceptionnothandled.aspx) may be of most interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a try/catch block in your app and make the app print the stack trace and than auto close.
Hope this can halp you :D

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but I don't think that changing the code is a valid solution to this problem because it is inconvenient and likely to lead to accidental changes if this is ever left in. Furthermore, the workflow I am trying to get is essentially what you would have working with java in a terminal or sublime text, so it should be possible in VS.